# How we can use RX framework in WCF for long running process and frequent UI updation?

Tags: c#, wcf, system.reactive

Recently i came to know about Rx framework and seems very promising. I have a doubt in it. Suppose from my UI [may it be winforms or web pages], i make a call to webservice and sending a List. So my calls is like --> myWCFServiceMethod(List empLists). Inside this service methods, for each employee object, i need to make again another service calls and   get the result of it and do some kind of DB operations [saving and updation] and finally sends back the status of each employee to the client side. For each employee in the lists, i have to do the same operation parallel. There is no sequential order.

Is that possible with Rx framework ? For doing this, should I need to implement callback contracts for each employees status updation back to client UI ?

I made the UI with a datagrid and the datagrid has 2 columns. firts is the employee name and second is the status column.

when UI loads, i loaded with 100 employee in the grid. Then clicks on the start button. So I packed up all the employee object into a list and sends that lists to the webservice method.

Now, i am looking for the things to do which is the status updation of each process when an employee goes through different process. Something like parallel process. There is no sequential process. If some employee object can finish its work early and some others will take some time. SO there is no order of process. Any employee can call its own associated external web service call and gets the result from it. One it got such a result, it then tries to save or update the DB. For all these process, I want to get notified the status of each process of an employee is going through and finally it finishes its work.

I dont understand without having callback contract how Rx can do this ?

I didnt see any similiar type of tutorials or guidance for how we can do it.

Please guide me through proper way.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick answer to your question.

To make multiple service calls in parallel and then get the results as they return you need a query like this:

```
var query =
    from index in indexes.ToObservable()
    from result in webServiceCall(index)
    select new { index, result };
```

The `webServiceCall` signature would look like `IObservable<R> webServiceCall(I index)`.

You then execute the query with:

```
query.Subscribe(ir =>
{
    // Do stuff with ir.index and ir.result
});
```

Focus on implementing `webServiceCall` to fit this code. I hope this gives you a starting point.

Comment: Yes. That was really fine. But when I used the above implementation, it is calling the webservicecall method sequentially. one by one. and the result is also getting one by one. Is there any way to start calling webservice method simultaneously. ie, if the grid has 20 items, then that 20 items should call the webservice method at the same time. So the i can show in the grid against each row status as "calling...". As the result comes in, it will update the UI. Please see the below question.

Comment: continuing...I am using the webservicecall method is like this. private IObservable<string> WebCallService(int index)
{ return Observable.Return(proxy.Method1(arg1, arg2, Scheduler.NewThread); } And in the subscription part, i am doing like this.  query.Subscribe(ir =>
            {
                UpdateUI(ir.index, ir.result);
            }); Is there anyway that I can call webservice method parallely and get the result parallely in RX framework ??

Comment: continuing...i also thought about FromAsyncPattern. But I dont have a Begin and End methods implemented on my local wcf service with namedpipe binding. Is there any way that we can call webservice parallel and get the results parallel in Rx framework ?

Comment: @Enigmativity is correct, and you are so close, however you WebService call is a problem. You are using Observable.Return. This will negate the point of being Async/concurrent. You should use the BeginEnd patterns but without it, just change your Observable.Return(proxy.Method1(arg1, arg2, Scheduler.NewThread); to be Observable.Start(()=>proxy.Method1(arg1, arg2),Scheduler.NewThread);

Comment: @AppleHead - Yes, Lee Campbell is correct. You need to use `Observable.Start` or some other Rx method that introduces concurrency. `Observable.Return` doesn't so that's why everything is running sequentially.

Comment: Hi, when using Observable.Start, it is started all the webservice calls paralell. Great !! execellent the power of Rx. But the service return value is sequentially. when we updating the UI after getting the result from webservice, it seems like updating row by row. I am studying it now. If possible, can u suggest any similiar type of idea in Rx ? I just replaced the Return with Start as shown below: private IObservable<string> WebCallService(int index) { return Observable.Start(proxy.Method1(arg1, arg2, Scheduler.NewThread); }. Is this allows only getting one data at a time ? Continues...

Comment: If I use the code block inside the private IObservable<string> WebCallService(int index) method as shown below, what would be the return value for this function ?                                   var start = Observable.Start(() => {
               string val = proxy.Method1(arg1, arg2, Scheduler.NewThread);            
               return val;
            }, Scheduler.NewThread);
            start.Subscribe(UpdatedUI, () => Updated2UI("Action completed"));
       // here what i should return // the return type is IObservable<string>

Comment: continues....  Do u see any advantage in this approach ?? My wcf service is having percall instancecontext and concurrency is multiple.

Comment: @AppleHead - You're asking a new question in your comments. I'd suggest you put it together as a new question because it is very difficult to read your code in questions and you're getting a very limited number of users reading these comments.