# Parallel execution inside WCF service method using RX or threading in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, system.reactive

halo there,

I am using VS 2010 and I have a winform client app and a wcf service. From my client, i will call wcf service. I implemented callback functionality and using netnamedpipe binding. I called a service method. This method is having a list of UserAccount object inside. This method will iterate through each UserAccount object and call a long runing propcess. At the end of each process, it will fire the event [callback] to notify the status of process. I am planning to do using a background worker for each process of UserAccount object. But Rx reactive framework is having something more credible functionalities which meets this requirement. Is there any parallel execution is possible in this case using RX ? I just invoke the wcf service call. The service method is doing all these long running process and report each process status back to the client code [where callback is implemented in the client].

```
1. Client ---> Wcf ----> wcf.DoLongRunning() ---> 
2. foreach (UserAccount usr in UserAccountLists)  // Is there anyway to avoid looping
   { 
       class A = new class(); 
       call A.Method1(usr) and A.Method2(usr) // call these 2 methods parallel.
       // these 2 methods have return values. how to handle that one also in Rx ???
   }
```

This seems parallel execution inside parallel execution.

Can anyone suggest a good approach for this functionality using Rx or any threading model.
Processing each object will take much more time. Any way to do parallel execution ??

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `Parallel.Foreach` ?

```
Parallel.ForEach<UserAccount>(UserAccountLists, usr =>
{
    classA A = new classA(); 
    A.Method1(usr);
    A.Method2(usr);
});
```

With `Parallel.Foreach` the code will wait for all operations to complete before proceeding.

The alternative would be to leave the foreach as it is and change the method calls to use `Task`:

```
Task t1 = new Task(() => A.Method1(usr));
t1.Start();

Task t2 = new Task(() => A.Method2(usr));
t2.Start();
```

This way the method will return before all operations are complete. So i guess it depends on what you want. Note that with the `Task` example the two methods will be run independently of one another, i don´t know if that´s ok in your case.

Edit:
A result of a Task can be accessed if the Task has a result type. Result type can be specified by giving the Task a generic parameter:
`Task<string>` will have result of `string`.

As for thousands Tasks: i don´t think it will be wise to simply create thousand Task objects. You can, however, search for various implementations of custom `TaskScheduler`s. That should give you more control over the creation and execution of "many" tasks.

Comment: thanks. here how i can get the result from each tasks ? If there is 2000 useraccounts, then 2000 task needs to create ? will it affect the performance ?

Comment: @user2017793 see my edit. Note that with Parallel.Foreach you wouldn´t have to worry about the number of accounts. The runtime will decide when and how many threads will be created.

Comment: As Jobo suggests look at the implementations of TaskScheduler. Some use Pooling (including Parallel.Foreach) so that a number (which is defined by the load on the OS) of Tasks are kicked off (e.g. 100) and as each Task finishes it would pick up the next queuing piece of work. So in your example the Tasks would average 20 useraccounts each.

Comment: Hi all, how about Observable.FromAsyncPattern ?? see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437506/how-we-can-use-rx-framework-in-wcf-for-long-running-process-and-frequent-ui-upda?rq=1